# R: sub-setting a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, quantmod

I am working with the data below and have a question on sub-setting the data frame:

```
library(quantmod)
library(pedquant)

#round to the nearest at-the-money strike & retrieve option chain
baba_option<-getOptionChain("BABA",Exp="2023-06-16")

mround<-function(x,base){
  base*round(x/base)
}

baba_ATM<-mround(baba_last,5)
> baba_ATM
[1] 90
```

Now we have 90 as the nearest ATM option strike and will then turn to option chain.

```
call_volume<-baba_option$calls$Vol
call_price<-baba_option$calls$Last
strike<-baba_option$calls$Strike
put_price<-baba_option$puts$Last
put_volume<-baba_option$puts$Vol

call_option_df<-data.frame(strike,call_volume,call_price)
```

*First question encountered:*

```
> put_option_df<-data.frame(strike,put_volume,put_price)
Error in data.frame(strike, put_volume, put_price) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 107, 104
```

As I only need focus on near-the-money options so I would like to subset the data frame, and as for now put option data frame is not yet built due to the previous encountered error.

Given the nearest strike is 90, and I will display the data sorted by +/-4 strikes from 90:

```
> subset(call_option_df,strike>=86.0 & strike<=94)
   strike call_volume call_price
31     86        2336       5.60
32     87         438       4.60
33     88         880       3.80
34     89        1052       2.98
35     90        9826       2.17
36     91        6514       1.49
37     92       18700       1.02
38     93       12245       0.64
39     94        6323       0.46
```

Second question is, given strike interval may not necessarily be 1, so instead of manually adding/subtracting number from ATM value, which is 90-4 & 90+4, is there a way I can retrieve 4 strikes up, 4 strikes down and at-the-money strike from the data?

Many thanks for your time and all ideas are welcome.